# How to edit a database in Python?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x

I am an absolute beginner in Python (3.3.2). I know the basic functions like writing text files, variables, loops ,etc but have never written complex code.

My research project requires applying a moving average filter on three columns of a large text file (150 MB in size, having more than 1 million rows). My question is: What should I study in order to develop a methodology to apply the moving average formula within Python?. Excel is not an option because doing so is very tedious in Excel and sometimes it crashes due to longer periods of loading.

Kindly direct me to the 'right' resources/ examples relevant to my problem. I have gone through several python tutorials but didn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It should have no problem handling 10**6 rows on commonly available modern hardware. And among its many goodies are functions for [computing moving averages](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments).